# Android SHH tunneling through school Wi-Fi

Tags: ssh, openssh, ssh-tunnel, socks-proxy, socks

Ok so I'll try my best to explain the situation at hand here. My school recently got a new web filter that blocks literally, everything. I can't use Google Drive or anything that I need anymore. Our school has Wi-Fi. What I'm wanting to do is SSH tunnel from my phone (Android). I have a SSH client on my phone and a SSH server set up already. I've also set up Firefox to handle SOCKS proxy for tunneling. Here's my problem. Almost all ports are blocked via the schools Wi-Fi. My SSH client won't connect through the WiFi because I guess that client uses a port that's blocked by the school. They DO NOT block port 22(SSH). So that makes me guess that my SSH client app uses a different port. Please help me as to what I can do to circumvent this problem of not being able to SSH into my server through school wifi. Thanks!

Comment: Try another SSH client that allows you to specify port 22

Comment: Can you name one? I've been looking for one. My guess would be that it'd take root access for an app to use port 22 on Android.

Comment: SuperUser isn't supposed to give software suggestions. Do the research yourself.